# DNS resolution failure

Tags: networking

Trying to connect my new Raspi to the internet for the first time via a cross-over to a bridged connection with my laptop's wi-fi.

The Raspi browser works for internal network webservers but won't receive anything from the WAN using either URL or ip address.  Get a name resolution failure and a fail to load page.

I'm thinking it must be router related as it only fails if going through the gateway router.

Any ideas what the issue might be and how to resolve it?

Comment: What's the output of the following commands? `ip addr show`
`ip route show`
`cat /etc/resolv.conf` I think your dhcp server has either not send the correct dns servers or routers to external networks. Did you try pinging a external server? `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` (This is a DNS Server from google).

Comment: Try running `traceroute 8.8.8.8`. Since external ping fails, we're interested in first few results.

Comment: Problem is resolved.  I rebooted the laptop this morning and the router. Re-instated the bridge in the laptop and suddenly things started to work.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then on the interfaces file you should have something like:

```
iface wlan0
```

Insert a new line exactly after that one with your DNS server (I will use google's for the example):

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Exactly like that and just reboot your pi via:

sudo reboot

That fixed mine, I hope it gets yours going!

Edit:

I also changed the content of the file resolv.conf on the /etc/ directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In which you will see something like:

```
domain gateway.2wire.net
search gateway.2wire.net
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Change the nameserver IP to whatever your DNS is.

Comment: this solution solve my problem after several hours crashing my head with it

Comment: This solution is specifically for if you're not using dhcpcd

Answer (score 1):

1. I modified a file using the command below:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
   ```
2. uncommented this line:

   > static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1.....blah blah blah

   it is in the third block from the bottom, seems to have worked

Comment: Can you please show the code that worked?